# Using nexus snapshot version airtifacts to deploy test servers

Tags: nexus

I need to transfer nexus snapshot package to test servers for testing purpose. So i need to identify the latest snapshot package url.

I have tried to use metadata.xml file but it only include the time stamp.To rebuild the full url we need the identify the time stamp and the last number.

EX:- foo-1.0-20110506.1100-1.jar

We can extract up to foo-1.0-20110506.1100 but we can not identify the last integer number.

-

-

Comment: Which version of nexus are you using ? NXRM2 always allowed to search for `latest` artifact. This is now possible in NXRM3 [since version 3.16.0](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14407)

Comment: We are using 3.15.2-01 version

Comment: It's not possible in prior versions, thus that ticket was such a big deal.